# Set additional required approver for pull requests at subfolder lever in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have a pull request policy on my repo which requires at least one member of the `devs` group reviews and approves any change before it is merged in to master. I'd like to be able to specify additionally that any files changes under the `sql_scripts` folder require a member of `dbadmin` group to review and approve.

Can this be done in Azure Devops using either the UI or the API?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this under branch policies.

From the GUI navigate to **Repos**-> then in the hamburger menu **branches**-> then select your master branch and then ... on choose **Branch Policies**. [Like so](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#configure-branch-policies)

Then from the branch policies page scroll down and find the **Add Automatic Reviewer** button and set a **path filter** based on the folder.